# Can Pandas XLSXWriter apply a chart template when inserting a chart?

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas, xlsxwriter

If not, is there a way to see the properties of a table that I have in excel so that I can use the same style and color properties?

Comment: have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723793/preserving-styles-using-pythons-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils-copy) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044349/how-do-i-use-excels-format-painter-across-a-whole-workbook)? I'm sure we can piece the two together.

Comment: Interesting. I think xlrd and xlutils.copy could potentially be what I am looking for. I will give it a try and update you. Thank you!